# php get html from a web site with cURL not function

Tags: php, curl

i have a problem. I'm trying to get html from a web site with cURL. It work fine in this mode:

```
  $c = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  //curl_setopt(... other options you want...)

  $html = curl_exec($c);

  if (curl_error($c))
      die(curl_error($c));

  // Get the status code
  $status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

  curl_close($c);
  $html = str_get_html($html);
```

But when i try to put the code in a function and call it in a second moment, not work! This code with a function:

```
function get_html_from_page($url) {
  $c = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  //curl_setopt(... other options you want...)

  $html = curl_exec($c);

  if (curl_error($c))
      die(curl_error($c));

  // Get the status code
  $status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

  curl_close($c);
  return $html;
}

//echo "Il contenuto del file è: ". $html . " con status: " . $status;
function get_last_vote_player() {

  echo '<table border="1"><theader>';
  echo '<td><b>Giocatore</b></td>';
  echo '<td><b>Voto</b></td>';
  echo '<td><b>Gol fatti/subiti</b></td>';
  echo '<td><b>Assist</b></td>';
  echo '<td><b>Rigori Realizzati</b></td>';
  echo '</theader><tbody>';

  $html = str_get_html(get_html_from_page('http://www.gazzetta.it/calcio/fantanews/voti/serie-a-2016-17/'));

  $dep = array();
  foreach($html->find('.magicTeamList') as $team) {
      $squadra = $team->first_child()->first_child()->last_child()->innertext;


      if (!in_array(ucwords($squadra),$dep)) {
          echo '<tr><td colspan="5"><b>'.ucwords($squadra).'</b></td></tr>';
          foreach($team->find('.playerName') as $player) {
              echo '<tr>';
              echo '<td>'.$player->find('a',0)->innertext . '</td>';
              //echo $player->innertext . '<br>';
              $voto = trim($player->next_sibling()->innertext);
              if ($voto == '-') $voto = 'S.V.'; else $voto = floatval($voto);
              echo '<td>' . $voto . '</td>';
              $golFatti = $player->next_sibling();
              echo '<td>'.$golFatti->next_sibling()->innertext . '</td>';
              $assist = $golFatti->next_sibling();
              echo '<td>'.$assist->next_sibling()->innertext . '</td>';
              $rigoriRealizzati = $assist->next_sibling();
              echo '<td>'.$rigoriRealizzati->next_sibling()->innertext . '</td>';
              echo '</tr>';
          }
      }

      $dep[] = ucwords($squadra);
  }
  echo '</tbody></table>';
}


get_last_vote_player();
```

And also when i try to call it into a class like this not work:

```
class WebPage {
    public $url = '';

    public function __construct($url) {
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    protected function get_html_from_page() {
      $c = curl_init($this->url);
      curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      //curl_setopt(... other options you want...)

      $html = curl_exec($c);

      if (curl_error($c))
          die(curl_error($c));

      // Get the status code
      $status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

      curl_close($c);
      return $html;
    } 
}

class PlayerVote extends WebPage {

    public function __construct($url) {
        parent::__construct($url);
    }

    public function get_last_vote_player() {

      echo '<table border="1"><theader>';
      echo '<td><b>Giocatore</b></td>';
      echo '<td><b>Voto</b></td>';
      echo '<td><b>Gol fatti/subiti</b></td>';
      echo '<td><b>Assist</b></td>';
      echo '<td><b>Rigori Realizzati</b></td>';
      echo '</theader><tbody>';

      $html = str_get_html($this->get_html_from_page('http://www.gazzetta.it/calcio/fantanews/voti/serie-a-2016-17/'));

      $dep = array();
      foreach($html->find('.magicTeamList') as $team) {
          $squadra = $team->first_child()->first_child()->last_child()->innertext;


          if (!in_array(ucwords($squadra),$dep)) {
              echo '<tr><td colspan="5"><b>'.ucwords($squadra).'</b></td></tr>';
              foreach($team->find('.playerName') as $player) {
                  echo '<tr>';
                  echo '<td>'.$player->find('a',0)->innertext . '</td>';
                  //echo $player->innertext . '<br>';
                  $voto = trim($player->next_sibling()->innertext);
                  if ($voto == '-') $voto = 'S.V.'; else $voto = floatval($voto);
                  echo '<td>' . $voto . '</td>';
                  $golFatti = $player->next_sibling();
                  echo '<td>'.$golFatti->next_sibling()->innertext . '</td>';
                  $assist = $golFatti->next_sibling();
                  echo '<td>'.$assist->next_sibling()->innertext . '</td>';
                  $rigoriRealizzati = $assist->next_sibling();
                  echo '<td>'.$rigoriRealizzati->next_sibling()->innertext . '</td>';
                  echo '</tr>';
              }
          }

          $dep[] = ucwords($squadra);
      }
      echo '</tbody></table>';
    }
}

$vote = new PlayerVote('http://www.gazzetta.it/calcio/fantanews/voti/serie-a-2016-17/');
$vote->get_last_vote_player();
```

Not work because when i try to go to the page, it response is "
Unable to reach the site"

Why?

Answer (score 1):

when you try to call it in a class... the error is on this line:

$html = str_get_html($this->get_html_from_page('http://www.gazzetta.it/calcio/fantanews/voti/serie-a-2016-17/'));

you need not pass the url in get_html_from_page as the function do not take any input... url is fetched using $this->url ....

change it to : 
  $html = str_get_html($this->get_html_from_page());

and it should work